# Regex for Mongo db from node.js is not working

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

I am using regex to fetch data from mongodb from my node js application which is not working. Here is the code snippet. the query can not match with the set of records.

```
var analysis_date = '/^'+moment(fromTime).format('YYYY-MM').toString()+'/';
user_analysis.find({
parent_id: usrId,
analysis_date: { 
    $regex : analysis_date 
   }
},function(err, result) {
//some Code goes here});
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it worked with the second way you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of specifying the regular expression as a string, try passing a `RegExp` object:

```
user_analysis.find({
    "parent_id": usrId,
    "analysis_date": new RegExp(analysis_date, 'i')
}, function(err, result) {
    // ...
});
```

If you want, you can also pass a string, but then you'll need to remove the `/` delimiters:

```
user_analysis.find({
    "parent_id": usrId,
    "analysis_date": {
        $regex: '^' + moment(fromTime).format('YYYY-MM').toString(),
        $options: "i"
    }
}, function(err, result) {
    // ...
});
```